# Behind the scenes, what's happening with decimal value type in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, types, decimal, primitive

How is the `decimal` type implemented?

**Update**

- It's a 128-bit value type (16 bytes)
- 1 sign bit
- 96 bits (12 bytes) for the mantissa
- 8 bits for the exponent
- remaining bits (23 of them!) set to 0

Thanks! I'm gonna stick with using a 64-bit long with my own implied scale.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Decimal Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point) article on Wikipedia with specific link to this article about [`System.Decimal`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx).

> A decimal is stored in 128 bits, even though only 102 are strictly necessary. It is convenient to consider the decimal as three 32-bit integers representing the mantissa, and then one integer representing the sign and exponent. The top bit of the last integer is the sign bit (in the normal way, with the bit being set (1) for negative numbers) and bits 16-23 (the low bits of the high 16-bit word) contain the exponent. The other bits must all be clear (0). This representation is the one given by decimal.GetBits(decimal) which returns an array of 4 ints.

Comment: The linked article was helpful; this Mr. Skeet seems like a reliable source for C#-related questions. He has many insightful articles.

Answer (score 7):

From the [C# Language Specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx):

> The `decimal` type is a 128-bit data type suitable for financial and monetary calculations.
>   The `decimal` type can represent values ranging from 1.0 × 10<sup>−28</sup> to approximately 7.9 × 10<sup>28</sup> with 28-29 significant digits.
>
> The finite set of values of type `decimal` are of the form (–1)<sup>*s*</sup> × *c* × 10<sup>-*e*</sup>, where the sign *s* is 0 or 1, the coefficient *c* is given by 0 ≤ *c* < 2<sup>96</sup>, and the scale *e* is such that 0 ≤ *e* ≤ 28.
>   The `decimal` type does not support signed zeros, infinities, or NaN's. A `decimal` is represented as a 96-bit integer scaled by a power of ten. For decimals with an absolute value less than 1.0m, the value is exact to the 28<sup>th</sup> decimal place, but no further.
>
> For decimals with an absolute value greater than or equal to 1.0m, the value is exact to 28 or 29 digits. Contrary to the `float` and `double` data types, decimal fractional numbers such as 0.1 can be represented exactly in the decimal representation.
>   In the `float` and `double` representations, such numbers are often infinite fractions, making those representations more prone to round-off errors.
>
> If one of the operands of a binary operator is of type `decimal`, then the other operand must be of an integral type or of type `decimal`. If an integral type operand is present, it is converted to `decimal` before the operation is performed.
>
> The result of an operation on values of type `decimal` is that which would result from calculating an exact result (preserving scale, as defined for each operator) and then rounding to fit the representation. Results are rounded to the nearest representable value, and, when a result is equally close to two representable values, to the value that has an even number in the least significant digit position (this is known as “banker’s rounding”). A zero result always has a sign of 0 and a scale of 0.
>
> If a decimal arithmetic operation produces a value less than or equal to 5 × 10<sup>-29</sup> in absolute value, the result of the operation becomes zero. If a decimal arithmetic operation produces a result that is too large for the `decimal` format, a `System.OverflowException` is thrown.
>
> The `decimal` type has greater precision but smaller range than the floating-point types. Thus, conversions from the floating-point types to `decimal` might produce overflow exceptions, and conversions from `decimal` to the floating-point types might cause loss of precision. For these reasons, no implicit conversions exist between the floating-point types and `decimal`, and without explicit casts, it is not possible to mix floating-point and `decimal` operands in the same expression.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead, the current one is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#838-the-decimal-type

Answer (score 1):

As described on MSDN's Decimal Structure page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(VS.80).aspx:

> The binary representation of a Decimal
>   value consists of a 1-bit sign, a
>   96-bit integer number, and a scaling
>   factor used to divide the 96-bit
>   integer and specify what portion of it
>   is a decimal fraction. The scaling
>   factor is implicitly the number 10,
>   raised to an exponent ranging from 0
>   to 28. Therefore, the binary
>   representation of a Decimal value is
>   of the form, ((-296 to 296) / 10(0 to
>   28)), where -296-1 is equal to
>   MinValue, and 296-1 is equal to
>   MaxValue.
>
> The scaling factor also preserves any
>   trailing zeroes in a Decimal number.
>   Trailing zeroes do not affect the
>   value of a Decimal number in
>   arithmetic or comparison operations.
>   However, trailing zeroes can be
>   revealed by the ToString method if an
>   appropriate format string is applied.

Answer (score 0):

From "CLR via C#" 3rd Edition by J.Richter:

> A 128-bit high-precision
>   floating-point value commonly used for
>   financial calculations in which
>   rounding errors can’t be tolerated. Of
>   the 128 bits, 1 bit represents the
>   sign of the value, 96 bits represent
>   the value itself, and 8 bits represent
>   the power of 10 to divide the 96-bit
>   value by (can be anywhere from 0 to
>   28). The remaining bits are unused.

Answer (score 0):

> The decimal keyword denotes a 128-bit data type.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.71).aspx)

> The binary representation of a Decimal value consists of a 1-bit sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the 96-bit integer and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction. The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent ranging from 0 to 28. Therefore, the binary representation of a Decimal value is of the form, ((-296 to 296) / 10(0 to 28)), where -296-1 is equal to MinValue, and 296-1 is equal to MaxValue.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> The decimal type is just another form
>   of floating point number - but unlike
>   float and double, the base used is 10.

A simple explanation is here http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx