# Multiplication error on double variable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Try this simple code..

```
double a=0.17;
double b=a*10000;
```

why variable b become 1700.0000000000002 instead of 1700 ?

I am using VS2010 with.Net framework 3.5
even tried with VS2012 with.Net framework 4.5

Comment: Use the decimal type instead of a double

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091993/inconsistency-rounding-real-numbers-in-c

Comment: Infinitlicate.... Means duplicate infinite times!!!