# How to print out the value of a DECIMAL (tagDEC) type?

Tags: c++, windows

I have to use the DECIMAL type (tagDEC struct) for higher precision.

But DECIMAL for C++ in windows api is just a struct.

```
typedef struct tagDEC {
    USHORT wReserved;
    union {
        struct {
            BYTE scale;
            BYTE sign;
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
        USHORT signscale;
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
    ULONG Hi32;
    union {
        struct {
            ULONG Lo32;
            ULONG Mid32;
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME2;
        ULONGLONG Lo64;
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME2;
} DECIMAL;
```

The value was from a peer (a C# program) with a .net DECIMAL struct via tcp socket.

Then how to display/print out its value in a friendly fashion such as - 12,345.678 * 10^(-21) in C++?

Comment: If I couldn't find a description of exactly how decimal values are encoded in that struct, I'd print out `scale`, `sign`, `Hi32` and `Lo64` for known values in a C# program and try to reverse engineer how it's encoded. When that is done, creating a `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DECIMAL& d);` function should be easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Behind the scenes, what's happening with decimal value type in C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294153/behind-the-scenes-whats-happening-with-decimal-value-type-in-c-net)

Comment: @TedLyngmo  This struct is from wtypes.h in Windows Kits. The value should be + or - (Hi32 * 2^64 + LO64) * 10^scale.

Comment: @Botje Not duplicated. I just updated my question. How to display/print out the value in C++. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple arbitrary-precision library (I found [this one](https://github.com/983/Num), liberally licensed, header only), this should be something like:

```cpp
DECIMAL input;
std::vector<Num::word> words{input.Lo64, input.Hi32};
Num n = Num(words.data(), words.data()+2, input.sign == 1).truncate() * Num(10).pow(input.scale);

std::vector<char> output;
n.print(output);
std::cout << output.data() << endl;
```

Comment: Several errors while build the library in visual studio 2019. num.hpp(230): error C2589: “(”:“::” ...

Comment: Please do a minimal amount of debugging. The line you mention is clobbered by a `max` definition from windows.h, so `#undef max`or `#define NOMINMAX`.